# Remove render-blocking JavaScript in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, blocking, render-blocking

Anyone Provide appropriate suggestion for how can i removed 
Remove render-blocking JavaScript from  Google page speed insights result.

My website is develop in WordPress

Thanks

Comment: Put your script in the bottom of the page body, is it already there?

Comment: may be this can help you https://pointblankpro.com/remove-render-blocking-javascript-and-css-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

find your all javascript calling into header or footer and 
Make JavaScript Asynchronous By default JavaScript blocks.
For example:

```
<script async src="my.js">
```

more details is here : https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS